# POST data from WCF to Website asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, rest

I'm working on project where I'm POSTING data from an android application to WCF service. I have created database in that WCF service where I'm temporary storing that data. now I need to POST that data to website which I have already created on asp.net. All I need to know how to post that data? What I need to do? I need a head start for that. I have followed some tutorial and add that service in my website as a `Add Service Reference`. is this a correct way to do this task ? or all I need to call my website using `httpwebClient`. or there are some other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: So you're wanting to send data from Android app -> WCF service -> website? That seems like a broken architecture; I'd normally expect (in an SOA world) for the website to be consuming the WCF service in a similar manner to the Android app, rather than the WCF app pushing data at your website...

Comment: Your question does not make sense. A database does not post data to a website. Are you just asking how to query a database from a website?

Comment: Thanks for your Response, my andriod app is not directly communicate with website. I have created WCF services for GET and POST data from android application. now all I need to do is consuming that WCF with my website. is it possible ?

Comment: @hugh thanks for your response too. I have mentioned that im just storing that data temporary in web service database. my core database is located on website which i have created on asp.net all I need to POST that data to my website database

Comment: Look into HttpClient to make calls to a REST service. If it's a normal WCF service, then it is business as usual as in adding the service as a service reference within the project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is there any reason why your WCF service cannot write the data directly to your web database?

Comment: @hugh you are not getting my point. the data which im posting from android to wcf I want that data into my project in VS. I have temporary created database into that wcf just for conforming that is my service is working or not. Thanks for your Response

Comment: @scheien I'm calling that RESTful service with HttpClient through android and it's working fine. my point is does i call my website project through wcf service using HTTPwebClient ? is it possible or the only solution is to add that service as a ADD service Reference

Comment: @MuneebAmjad - now I really do not understand. You want the data in your Visual Studio project? As in a file?

Comment: @hugh yeah exactly I want that data in my VS project as a object or in the form of array. it doesn't matter what form it will be. I need that data for further use.

Comment: json will be the best option @hugh